# ASP.NET Core naming conventions

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

Is it a good practice not to add "Service", "Model" to service and model names?

For example Users instead of UsersService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Although ASP.NET Core doesn't have strict naming conventions in services and models naming, but it's required for readability. For example, `User` can be domain entity in database, it can be also name of model (`UserModel => User`) or it can be service (`UserService => User`) in your case. It's confusing and leads to typos/errors. Class name should be descriptive and in this case class name doesn't tell anything about class itself. Also this naming convention is very common so everyone will be able to understand your code much faster. That's why I strictly recommend to follow these naming conventions in projects.